# Unable to make remote remote desktop connection

Tags: rdp

I run a small network with around 50 remote clients using VPN to connect to Head office.VPN is built using no-ip.org as DNS.I am unable to RDP to one of remote client wheras the same clinet is able to RDP to my workstation.Kindly advise solution for above problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Can you resolve the name of the remote machine?  Ping it by name and see if you can resolve it to an IP.  If no, either fix your DNS or use its IP address.
- Is RDP enabled on the remote workstation? On Windows 7, go to Control Panel -> System -> Remote settings. Make sure that "Don't allow connections to this computer" is not selected. Check your Windows Firewall to see that it is either turned off or the appropriate exclusion (port 3389 in) is in place.
- Can you access port 3389 across the network?  RDP requires TCP port 3389.  Try to run "telnet workstation01 3389" and see what happens. If it is successful, you will get a blank screen as if the connection is awaiting more data. If it fails, it will say connection was refused or failed. If the connection fails you likely need to add firewall ACLs to your network device(s).

Comment: I am able to Ping and IP->Name resolving is also fine. RDP is enabled & Firewall is turned off.i have tired alll this before but the issue remained unfixed.

Comment: telnet ws01 3389 is successful?